# Why Converting Hexadecimal number to byte in Java is not working?

Tags: java, c++, byte

`"byte FOO = 0xFE;"`
Doesn't work in java.

`"Cannot convert from into to byte"` but it works on C++. 
How to solve this?

Comment: A good step to take is to stop programming in Java as if it were C++. The fact this compiles in C++ is pretty irrelevant to transcribing your ideas into Java.

Answer (score 8):

Value `0xFE` is equivalent to `254` in `int`, and is not in the range of byte, so no implicit typecasting would be done, if you try to store it in a byte. 
Your RHS value must be in range `[-128 to 127]` to get accommodated in byte.

Or, you can tell the compiler explicitly to store it, by `explicit typecasting`:

```
byte FOO = (byte)0xFE;
```

However, if you store a value that can fit in range of `byte` then no explicit typecasting would be needed.

```
byte FOO = 0x20;  // OK, can accommodate in byte.
```

See [JLS - Section # 5.1](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1) for more details about type conversions.

And [JLS - Section # 5.2](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.2) which specifically discusses `Assignment Conversion`

To quote a statement from [`JLS`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.2): -

> A narrowing primitive conversion may be used if the type of the
>   variable is byte, short, or char, and the value of the constant
>   expression is representable in the type of the variable.

Answer (score 2):

Either:

```
long FOO = 0xFE; //Use long as type
```

or

```
byte FOO = (byte)0xFE; //Typecast to byte.
```

By using hexadecimal numbers, The compiler will identify if the value fits between the range for byte [-128, 127]. Since, `0xFE` is greater than `127`, you will have to use an `int` or `long` since it's out of range for `byte`.

Your example is called [Narrowing conversion](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.3).